# ¿Para qué se utiliza self en POO en Python?

Tags: python, poo

Estoy aprendiendo Python y me topé con la parte de POO. En su momento hice mis pinitos con la POO de PHP pero me pasa lo mismo, no entiendo que se utilice el valor *self* dentro de un método.

He estado leyendo por internet y habla de autoreferenciar a la clase y demás, pero sinceramente, no entiendo ese concepto.

Por ejemplo:

```
class Persona:

    def inicializar(self,nom):
        self.nombre=nom

    def imprimir(self):
        print("Nombre",self.nombre)

persona1=Persona()
persona1.inicializar("Pedro")
persona1.imprimir()

persona2=Persona()
persona2.inicializar("Carla")
persona2.imprimir()
```

¿Alguien sería tan amable de explicarme para qué sirve ese `self`?

Comment: Las respuestas que te han dado son suficientes para hacerte una idea ahora que estás empezando. Pero cuando profundices más, mírate el `protocolo descriptor` que es el responsable del funcionamientos interno de la POO en python. En python se tiene herencia múltiple, no siendo posible saber *a priori* en qué orden buscar el método a ejecutar sin conocer la instancia en concreto que lo están invocando. De ahí que sea importante indicar la instancia, por convenio como `self`.

Comment: Gracias @ChemaCortes lo tengo en cuenta. Ha sido muy útil toda la información aquí recogida.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En **Python** casi todo es un objeto, a diferencia de otros lenguajes, una clase es un objeto también, suena raro pero efectivamente es así:

```
class Prueba():
  pass

p = Prueba()

print(type(Prueba))
print(type(p))

> <class 'type'>
> <class 'Prueba'>
```

Podemos observar que la clase `Prueba` es un objeto del tipo `<class 'type'>` y el objeto instanciado es ahora si, del tipo `<class 'Prueba'>`. Con esto en mente puede que sea más claro el porque del uso del `self`. Supongamos algo parecido a tu ejemplo:

```
class Persona:

    def __init__(self,nom):
        self.nombre=nom

    def imprimir(self):
        print("Nombre: {0}".format(self.nombre))

p1 = Persona("Juan")
p2 = Persona("Pedro")
print(type(Persona))
print(type(p1))
print(type(p2))

> <class 'type'>
> <class 'Persona'>
> <class 'Persona'>
```

Hemos usado el objeto `Persona` del tipo `<class 'type'>` (clase) para crear dos nuevos objetos de `<class 'Persona'>`. La forma normal de acceder a los métodos sería haciendo esto:

```
p1.imprimir())
p2.imprimir())
> Juan
> Pedro
```

Pero lo que en realidad está ocurriendo por debajo, es decir lo que **Python** hace en realidad, es algo así:

```
Persona.imprimir(p1))
Persona.imprimir(p2))
> Juan
> Pedro
```

Una forma de ver esto es que cada instancia `p1` y `p2` no posee "copias" del método `imprimir` no tiene sentido, el método es de la clase `Persona`, los datos `self.nombre` si, son de cada instancia. De modo que para que `Persona` pueda invocar `imprimir` pero con los datos de la instancia adecuada, es necesario declarar el método como  `imprimir(<instancia>)`.

Aclaración: `self` es una convención podríamos usar cualquier nombre pero no es recomendable.

Comment: Interesante! Desconocía lo que comentas. Gracias!

Answer (score 6):

Para completar y para tener en cuenta. El uso de `self` es una convención en Python, una buena práctica pero no una regla (no es una palabra reservada ni nada por el estilo).

Con esto quiero decir que puedes usar cualquier nombre para representar la instancia de la clase:

```
>>> class A:
...   def __init__(instancia, numero):
...     instancia.numero = numero
...   def get_numero(instancia):
...     return instancia.numero
... 
>>> a = A(10)
>>> a.get_numero()
10
```

Para Python esto es una clase perfectamente normal. En la clase `A` he cambiado el `self` por `instancia`. **Ojo**, esto es solo una aclaración.

También te puedes encontrar con algunos métodos que carecen de `self` como cuando se usan métodos estáticos:

```
>>> class A:
...   def __init__(self, numero):
...     self.numero = numero
...   @staticmethod
...   def saludo():
...     print('Hola')
... 
>>> a = A(10)
>>> a.saludo()
Hola
```

El uso de `self` como el primer argumento de los métodos está especificado en [Function and method arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments) del PEP 8 (la guía de estilos para el código en Python).

Comment: Gracias! Aún no llegué a la parte de métodos estáticos por lo que no entiendo lo que son :) .

Answer (score 4):

El parámetro `self` se refiere al objeto instanciado de esa clase sobre el cual se está invocando dicho método. Es decir, el objeto que usaste para llamar al método (en tu ejemplo `persona1` y `persona2`).

Python, dentro de los métodos definidos de una clase, establece que el primer parámetro definido en un método recibirá el objeto con el cual se invoca dicho método. Este parámetro (que se suele llamar `self` aunque se puede usar cualquier nombre de variable [***ver comentarios***]) es usado dentro de la implementación del método para modificar el contenido o atributos de dicho objeto como desees.

Por lo tanto, es una condición necesaria que todos los métodos de una clase que puedan ser llamados a través de un objeto tengan al menos un parámetro, el cual se asignará automáticamente al objeto usado en la invocación.

Aunque en la definición del método, `self` es el primer parámetro, a la hora de llamar a dicho método no hace falta pasarle el propio objeto como primer parámetro explícitamente ya que Python lo hace de manera implícita sin necesidad de hacerlo manualmente. Es decir, el primer parámetro `self` del método se asigna automáticamente al propio objeto y el resto de parámetros a los argumentos con que llames al método.

En el caso del método `__init__()`, el parámetro `self` se refiere al objeto recién instanciado de la clase que quieres obtener al crear dicho objeto con `Nombre_Clase()`.

`self` es el equivalente al `this` de otros lenguajes (aunque `self` no es palabra reservada como `this` [***ver comentarios***]), con la diferencia de que en otros lenguajes no hace falta definir los métodos con un parámetro `this`, mientras que en Python sí es necesario.

Comment: Solo para añadir algo, `self` es algo en lo que [todos los desarrolladores se ponen de acuerdo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019627/python-self-keyword) y no es una palabra reservada de Python, es solo que es mas fácil cuando se usa de esa manera.

Comment: @Kenny Muchas gracias Kenny, no lo sabía. Ya lo he editado aclarándolo para que no haya confusión.

Comment: Quedo bien la edición. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias a ambos!

Answer (score 0):

Como tu mismo dices, es una auto referencia y en general, en un método de instancia de un modelo, deberías usar self cuando modifiques atributos o cuando exista alguna ambigüedad entre llamar a una variable local y un atributo/método ya definido. Esto sucede en todos los lenguajes que usan POO y es una practica muy común y la mas correcta, por lo que te aconsejo que lo uses.

Comment: Es lo que más o menos entendí yo cuando buscaba info. Que sin el self es local, para ese método, pero con el self se pueden utilizar en diferentes métodos dentro de esa clase.