# Duda sobre listas en clases y en funciones [Python3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo una pequeña duda: Tengo una lista vacía llamada "personas" en una clase llamada "ListaPersona". Dentro de esa clase tengo una función y dentro de esta tiene una variable llamada self.personas. ¿self.personas es igual a la lista vacía o es otra variable?

```
class ListaPersona: 
        personas=[]

        def __init__(self):
            self.personas
```

Comment: `self.personas` hace referencia a la misma lista inicializada con `persona = []` a no ser que reasignes un nuevo objeto, pero ten en cuenta que es un atributo de clase, no de instancia por lo que todas las instancias de `ListaPersona` comparten el mismo objeto personas... Mírate: [Diferencia entre atributos de instancia y atributos de clase](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/132561/15089). En cuanto al uso de `self` mírate: [¿Para qué se utiliza self en POO en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90357/para-qu%c3%a9-se-utiliza-self-en-poo-en-python)

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda!!